# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

In my nuxtjs project, I have 2 arrays of objects defined in data like below:

```
allCampusObj: [{
         name: "allCampus",
         title: "Campus",
      }],
      deptSummaryFieldsArr:[
        {
          name: "sisSchoolTitle",
          title: "School",
          formatter(value) {
            return value.length > 3 ? `${value.slice(0, 3)}...` : `${value}`;
          }
        },
        { 
          name: "sisDeptTitle",
          title: "Department",
          formatter(value) { 
            return "";
          }
        }, 
        {
          name: "secAll",
          title: "Courses"
        },
        {
          name: "secNSub",
          title: "Not Submitted"
        },
        {
          name: "nsp-slot",
          title: "% Not Submitted"
        },
        {
          name: "secSub",
          title: "Submitted"
        },
        {
          name: "sp-slot",
          title: "% Submitted"
        }
      ],
      deptSummaryFields: [
        ...this.allCampusObj, 
        ...this.deptSummaryFieldsArr
        ]
```

I am getting the error saying Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method. Even if I have used spread operator on arrays

Comment: Have you tried removing ```formatter``` function from an  ```deptSummaryFieldsArr``` variable and then try again. Might be because its an function hence spread operator is not able to inherit it.

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena, yes tried that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly reference `this` in [javascript initializer notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) unless it is in a function-like value.

As noted  in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers), there are several ways to get around this limitation. Below is one of many approaches.
Note, as mentioned in the comments, you have a syntax error with your function declaration, which should be written as `formatter : (value)=> {return "";}`

```
const obj = {
  allCampusObj: [{
    name: "allCampus",
    title: "Campus",
    formatter : (value)=> {
        return "";
      }
  }],
  deptSummaryFieldsArr: [
    {
      name: "sisSchoolTitle",
      title: "School",
      formatter: (value) => {
        return value.length > 3 ? `${value.slice(0, 3)}...` : `${value}`;
      }
    },
    {
      name: "sisDeptTitle",
      title: "Department",
      formatter:(value)=> {
        return "";
      }
    },
    {
      name: "secAll",
      title: "Courses"
    },
    {
      name: "secNSub",
      title: "Not Submitted"
    },
    {
      name: "nsp-slot",
      title: "% Not Submitted"
    },
    {
      name: "secSub",
      title: "Submitted"
    },
    {
      name: "sp-slot",
      title: "% Submitted"
    }
  ],
}
const obj2 = {
  deptSummaryFields: [
    ...obj.allCampusObj,
    ...obj.deptSummaryFieldsArr
  ]
}
obj.deptSummaryFields = obj2.deptSummaryFields;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: my arrays were defined in data object (nuxt js) only, so "this" is not creating any problem, also why to make object for obj2? why not array?

Comment: @developer It *does* create problems, `this.allCampusObj` is `undefined`. Please read the linked question. But yes, the `obj2` is unnecessary, one could have directly created the array and assigned it to `obj.deptSummaryFields`.